# Sql error: invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

I have a query which I'm trying to execute in sql gives me an error:

```
SELECT this_.pName as y0_
       , this_.kNum as y1_
       , aid1_.AID as y2_
       , COUNT(DISTINCT this_.agentG) as y3_ 
FROM AM_CPView this_
INNER JOIN AM_MView aid1_ ON this_.agentG= aid1_.AgentG
GROUP BY this_.pName, this_.kNum
```

this gives an error:

```
Column 'AM_MView.AID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Can anyone help me with the error? Thanks

Comment: The error seems clear.  You can remove the column from the `select`, add it to the `group by`, or put make it the argument to an aggregation function such as `max()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an aggregate function such as count in a `SELECT` and you're also grouping by non-aggregated columns then all the non-aggregated columns in your `SELECT` must also appear in the `GROUP BY`. Your query should thus be fixed with:

```
SELECT this_.pName as y0_
       , this_.kNum as y1_
       , aid1_.AID as y2_
       , COUNT(DISTINCT this_.agentG) as y3_ 
FROM AM_CPView this_
INNER JOIN AM_MView aid1_ ON this_.agentG= aid1_.AgentG
GROUP BY this_.pName, this_.kNum, aid1_.AID
```